# Moving first element moved to the end of the list - Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am having trouble writing a function that will move the first element to the end of the list every time it is called. I have tried using a combination of reverse and cdr to cut off the elements at either end, but cannot figure out how to add the elements to the correct end. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Correct outcomes:

(first_to_last '(1 2 3))

(2 3 1)

(first-to-last (first-to-last '(1 2 3)))

(3 1 2)

Comment: (reverse(cdr(reverse(cdr(reverse b))))) allows me to remove the first and last elements off of the list, but I don't know how to go about moving the elements to the correct places.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-doing the reversing, personally.

What we want is a list consisting of `cdr x` with `car x` appended to the end. The one trick here is that `car x` isn't a list, so we want to convert it to a list before appending it:

```
(define (first-to-last x) (append (cdr x) (list (car x))))
```

If you wanted to stick to the fundamentals, `cons` is the really fundamental way to put things together into lists, but it would be a bit more work. You'd basically end up defining something essentially identical to `append` in terms of `cons`. That's pretty easy but kind of pointless, given that `append` already exists.

Edit: I guess if you want to use `reverse` for some reason or other, you could do something like this:

```
(define (first-to-last x) (reverse (cons (car x) (reverse (cdr x)))))
```

It's a bit longer and strikes me as kind of clumsy, but it ought to work anyway.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot more sense. So if I wanted to do the opposite of this (move the last element to the first), I would simply want to do the same process but use the last function?

Comment: @user1023900: yes, that sounds about right. Here, reversing might make sense: last-to-first, is (reverse(first-to-last(reverse x))). That's probably not the most *efficient* way to do the job, but it is a really simple one.

Comment: Asymptotically, one reverse isn't any different from two reverses.